# Construct a T-SQL query for the following requirement

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
ID   Date1   T1   Date2   T2   Date3   T3   Date4   T4
1   DT11     Y    ----------NULL-----------------------  
2   DT11     N    DT22    Y    ----------NULL----------  
3   DT31     N    DT32    Y    DT33    Y    --NULL-----  
4   ----NULL---   DT42    Y    ---NULL---   DT44    Y
5   DT51     Y    ---NULL--    DT53    Y    --NULL-----
```

I have a table Table1 with the above structure.

Requirements:

1. Check which of (T1 - T5) has a 'Y' in it
2. If there are multiple 'Y', compare the dates to get the most recent date
3. Set a value in a new field with the name or part of the name of the date field with the most recent date.

So, the o/p should be

```
ID  Most-recent-Date-Flag
---------------------------------------------------    
1  "Date1 or T1"  -> Since all others are null
2  "Date2 or T2"  -> T2 has 'Y'
3  "Date3 or T3"  -> one 'N' and multiple 'Y', DT33 is most recent
4  "Date4 or T4"  -> multiple 'Y', DT44 is most recent
5  "Date5 or T5"  -> multiple 'Y', DT53 is most recent
```

I have managed to create the query to compare the dates. It is as follows:

```
    SELECT [ID]
    , MAX(UNPIVOT_DATE) AS MOST_RECENT_DATE
    FROM 
    (
    SELECT
    [ID]
    ,[Date1]
    ,[Date2]
    ,[Date3]
    ,[Date4]
    FROM TABLE1
    )SRC_TABLE
    UNPIVOT
    (
    UNPIVOT_DATE
    FOR DATES IN
    (
    [Date1]
    ,[Date2]
    ,[Date3]
    ,[Date4]
    )
    )UNPIVOT_TABLE
    GROUP BY [ID]
```

I am stuck at the point where i check for the 'Y' in (T1-T4) fields and to get the column name of the most recent date after comparison.

Hope this explanation helps!

08/04/2013
Thanks much @MarcinJuraszek. It works!! Is there anyway I can pass the column-name of the field(T1-T4) too? I tried the following and it did not work.

```
SELECT t.[ID]
,MAX(t.Date) as MOST_RECENT_DATE
--,t.Column_Name 
FROM
(
    SELECT [ID]
    ,[Date1] as Date
    ,[T1] as T
--  ,COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('Table1'), 2) AS Column_Name 
    FROM Table1
UNION ALL
    SELECT [ID]
    ,[Date2] as Date 
    ,[T2] as T 
--    ,COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('Table1'), 4) AS Column_Name
    FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT [ID] 
    ,[Date3] as Date
    ,[T3] as T 
--    ,COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('Table1'), 6) AS Column_Name
    FROM Table1
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT [ID]
    ,[Date4] as Date
    ,[T4] as T 
--    ,COL_NAME(OBJECT_ID('Table1'), 8) AS Column_Name 
    FROM Table1
) t
WHERE t.T = 'Y'
GROUP BY t.[ID]
--, t.Column_Name
ORDER by [ID]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: thanks marc_s! am a first timer here...didnt know how to do it!! :)

Comment: It's helpful with questions on StackOverflow to show your line of reasoning, and specifically where you got stuck. Show us what you've done and we're happy to help, but asking others to write code for you is impolite

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Snoozer. The question above has been edited to include the work that i have done until now.

Comment: This is generally a sign of a poorly designed schema - if all of the values that can appear in `T1` - `T4` (or in `Date1` - `Date4`) are really the same "sort" of thing, they ought to only be in a *single* column. They ought to be modelled as up to 4 *rows* of data, consisting of (whatever the number 1-4 signifies) in one column, and then just the `T` and `Date` columns.

Answer (score 0):

How about that:

```
SELECT t.ID, MAX(t.Date) FROM
  (SELECT ID, Date1 as Date, T1 as T FROM Test
  UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Date2 as Date, T2 as T FROM Test
  UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Date3 as Date, T3 as T FROM Test
  UNION ALL 
    SELECT ID, Date4 as Date, T4 as T FROM Test) t
WHERE t.T = 'Y'
GROUP BY t.ID
```

**[Simple Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d561b/18)**

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `GROUP BY` + `MAX()`, you could use `CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1)`. That would let you return other data along with the maximum date:

```
SELECT
  t.*,
  x.Date,
  x.FlagName
FROM TABLE1 AS t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1
    Date,
    FlagName
  FROM (
    SELECT Date1, T1, 'T1' UNION ALL
    SELECT Date2, T2, 'T2' UNION ALL
    SELECT Date3, T3, 'T3' UNION ALL
    SELECT Date4, T4, 'T4' UNION ALL
    SELECT Date5, T5, 'T5'
  ) AS s (Date, T, FlagName)
  WHERE T = 'Y'
  ORDER BY Date
) AS x
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up with the following query (by accident) and it worked.....

1. I created a view as given below

   CREATE VIEW View_Test as
   select 
   [ID], 
   case when [T1] = 'Y' then [D1] else null end as [D1],
   case when [T2] = 'Y' then [D2] else null end as [D2],
   case when [T3] = 'Y' then [D3] else null end as [D3],
   case when [T4] = 'Y' then [D4] else null end as [D4]
   from Test

Then i used the view in an unpivot query as given below

```
select [ID], max(DATE_FIELD) as most_recent_date, max(Flag) as most_recent_flag
from View_Test
unpivot (
DATE_FIELD for Flag in 
(
[D1]
, [D2]
, [D3]
,[D4]
)
) as DATE_Unpivoted
group by [ID]
ORDER BY [ID]
```

When i executed the above query, the "max(flag)" gave me the name of the date-field that had the most recent date. I still have no idea how it works. That bit about "flag" is still not understandable to me. But i left it in the query by accident...copy and paste from a different query that i tried and didnt work :)

Can anyone enlighten please? :)